# Microsoft Access force override table row ID

Tags: microsoft-access

I have a table with a missing record, when I recreate it (18) the new id is 127 because it's `autoincrement`. When I go to change the row id to 18 (and there is obviously no row with the id 18) it doesn't allow me to change it.

I've attempted to export the data as XML, change the id to 18 and import/append data however that doesn't seem to do anything.

So how do I force Access to recreate the table row 18 when I have over a hundred rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no single magical command without using SQL.  The easier way to do it is per this Microsoft KB article:  [How to reset an AutoNumber field value in Access](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812718)